# Should technical research papers contain a 'Proposed solution' in them?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, workshop

I want to publish a paper for the literature study that I have performed instead of the way I have implemented it (Planning to do this in another research paper). I have, however, evaluated different approaches that we can take to do this kind of work (Sentiment analysis). But when I submitted it to a workshop, it was rejected with the following,

> "However, the paper does not provide any detailed information, either
>   theoretical or technical, regarding their proposed approach, how they would
>   seek to evaluate this approach and the strengths and weaknesses of this
>   approach as a set of interlinked concepts." and "doesn't have any experimental comparison of the methods being reviewed."

Can you please explain?

Comment: Why do you want to publish the literature study and the implementation separately?

Answer (score 3):

> Should technical research papers contain a 'Proposed solution' in them?

In general, and particularly for a workshop, the answer to your title question would be "yes". The basic principle behind a workshop is that participants go there with some work-in-progress, discuss their ideas and next steps, and get early outside feedback. If you don't even tell *what* your ideas are, what is there to discuss? *"Here is what others have tried, end of story"* isn't really a great discussion starter.

Of course, survey papers exist, but a publishable survey is not just the Related Work section of a regular paper. Good surveys, such as those published in [ACM Computing Surveys](http://csur.acm.org), are lengthy and comprehensive treatments of a subject. Workshops are not the right venue for such papers.

There is also the added problem that your approach of publishing the state of the art report first, and then writing another paper about your actual idea, sounds a lot like finding the [Least Publishable Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_publishable_unit), a practice that many take offence with.